# Праля чоловічого роду

Tags: морфологія, фемінітиви

Як назвати чоловіка-пралю? Щодо деяких жіночих професій стосовно чоловіків пропонується використовувати описові звороти, наприклад, балерина — артист балету, манікюрниця — майстер манікюру. А який зворот дібрати до професії праля?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У наш час офіційно не існує ані професії «праля», ані професії «пральник».

Натомість [є](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B9):

- готувач пральних розчинів;
- завідувач пральні;
- **оператор пральних машин**;
- оператор пральні самообслуговування.

Це в тому ж стилі, що й «артист балету».

Тема ж неофіційних назв закрита [іншою відповіддю](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/3004). <sub>(При цьому, що цікаво, «балерун» є суто розмовним варіантом, «пральник» вважається стилістично нейтральним, а «манікюрник» є навіть офіційною назвою.)</sub>

Answer (score 6):

[Словник української мови: в 11 томах. — Том 7, 1976. — Стор. 515.](http://sum.in.ua/s/praljnyk)

> **ПРА́ЛЬНИК**, **~а**, *чоловічий рід* Робітник, що працює у пральні, на пральній матиці, що займається пранням білизни.
>
> *Десять пральників працювали спокійно й уперто* ([Натан Рибак](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), Новий день, 1937, 109).

---

**Зауваження.** Наросток **~ик** [часто] чергується з **~иця**, зворотньо теж працює: тому *манікюрниця* → *[манікюрник](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA&lr=-lang_ru)* <sup>g</sup>, порівняйте: *[прибиральник](http://sum.in.ua/s/prybyraljnyk)* → *[прибиральниця](http://sum.in.ua/s/prybyraljnycja)*.

Є також і пара до *балерини* — *балерун*, але наразі то розмовне слово.

[Словник української мови у 20 томах](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=179952&page=104)

> **БАЛЕРУ́Н**, **~а**, *чоловічий рід, **розмовне*** Артист балету; танцівник.
>
> *На гастролі поїде ціла трупа – 120 осіб, серед яких балерини, балеруни, симфонічний оркестр, художники і технічні працівники* (з газ.); *Стрункий балерун;*
>
> У порівнянні. *А вишибала цілує ручки нареченій, розкланюється, як балерун* (А. Крижанівський).